# Footer moves strangely at Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is my HTML & Javascript code:

```css
footer {
    background-color: #049e8c;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50pt;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
    <div id="" class="">
        <a href="#">hoge</a>
        <a href="#">hoge</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

"Javascript"

[Jscode](https://blog.webcreativepark.net/2007/11/16-012253.html)

I want Edge to be like this

[image: Edge][image: chrome]

Edge does not fit on the screen. Also, footer stops on the spot.

I tried both Javascript and CSS but it didn't work on Edge when there is no element at the bottom of the screen. I want to be at the bottom of the page when there are more elements than the screen.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make sure the content of your _JavaScript_ code is understandable to all users i.e. make it English. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you want the footer to be at the bottom edge to edge?

Comment: @MTBthePRO Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using CSS grids for all HTML templates. Otherwise it can be difficult to keep footer at the bottom for all screen sizes.
That being said, try using flexbox.

Insert all of your html in `main` and flexbox will push footer to the bottom of the page.

```css
/* The magic: */
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Stlyes to make the demo easier to see: */
body { margin: 0; }
header { background-color: #FD2D; }
main { background-color: #DFDD; }
footer { 
    background-color: #049e8c;
    height: 50pt;
    text-align: right;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main class="Site-content">Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

If you want to try **CSS Grids**, you need to do something like this.
All HTML content goes into the `Site-content` section. Hope this helped :)

```css
/* Stlyes to make the demo easier to see: */
html{
      height: 100%;
    }
    
 body { 
  margin: 0; 
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-areas:
        "header_section"
        "Site-content_section"
        "footer_section";
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100% 50px; /* 100px for header, 100% for content section, 50px for footer */
}
.header { 
grid-area: header_section;
background-color: #FDD; 
}
.Site-content { 
grid-area: Site-content_section;
background-color: #DFD; 
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer_section;
  background-color: #049e8c;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class= "header">Header</div>
  <div class="Site-content">Content</div>
  <div class= "footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get the point inside the question. Maybe If You want to put your footer full the windows you can try to use "position" with the value "absolute

```css
  footer {
   position:absolute;
   background-color: #049e8c;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50pt;
   text-align: right;
   margin-top: auto;
   bottom: 0;
   left:0;
  }
```

```html
 <body>
  <footer id="footer">
   <div id="" class="">
    <a href="#">hoge</a>
    <a href="#">hoge</a>
   </div>
  </footer>
 </body>
```

Comment: It's fine when nothing is displayed on the screen, but how can I make it go down when the page stretches?